# Ubuntu 22.04 Stuck in loading screen (Virtual Box)

Tags: boot, virtualbox

I've installed ubuntu in virtualbox 1 month and i rebooted the VM today and i got stuck in loading screen.

I restarted ton of times, the same problem. I restart my PC again the same.
I tried like all the solutions i found on google and here in the forum nothing.

Stuck here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDaqQ.png

I pressed ESC and no errors, all say "OK": https://i.stack.imgur.com/saptW.png

Any ideas? I dont want to reinstall :/

Comment: At grub screen press arrow down key to select start rescue shell option.

Answer (score 0):

You should use at least **4097 MB of RAM and no Shared clipboard**, otherwise stucks.